# how do you use the prompting funtion in batch

Tags: batch-file

Does anyone know why this isn't working

```
@echo off
set /p "%pass%=enter password>"
if exist "%pass%"="#####" (goto :passed)
exit
:passed
echo "it worked"
```

Comment: Remove the quotes and % from around the variable in the `set /p` line and try again. In the future, learn to be more specific here. *This isn't working* is a useless problem description unless you explain what *isn't working* means.

Comment: @KenWhite, nothing wrong with having the quotes.  They are the preferred method in my best practice book.

Comment: The `EXIST` option for the `IF` command is to check for the existence of a file.  Says it right in the HELP file.  Maybe you were thinking of using the `DEFINED` option with the `IF` command but even that does not need to be used.  Just remove the `exist` and use two equals signs per the `IF` commands documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much! Next time I will be more specific about the description.

Answer (score 1):

Something more like this:

```
@echo off 
set /p "pass=enter password> "
If "%pass%"=="#####" (goto :passed)
exit
:passed
echo "it worked"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do

**if you were trying to check if the password is '####' and authenticate use this**

```
@echo off

SET /p pass="enter password>" REM change this to get it to work

IF "%pass%"=="####" ( 
GOTO passed 

) ELSE (
EXIT
)

:passed
echo "it worked"
```

you were not setting the variable Pass here,

if you want to check for a file named #### and run :passed if the file exists then use this code *although I think this is not what you tried*

```
@echo off 

SET /p %pass%="enter password>" REM change this to get it working
IF EXIST %pass%="####" (goto :passed)
EXIT

:passed
echo "it worked"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want also hide your password input with `*******`

You can try this batch file :

```
@echo off
Title %~n0 by Hackoo 2016
Mode 50,5 & Color 0E
:CreatePassword
cls & Color 0E
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Call :InputPassword "Please choose your password" pass1
Call :InputPassword "Please confirm your password" pass2
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
If !pass1!==!pass2! ( Goto:Good ) Else ( Goto:Bad )
::***********************************
:InputPassword
Cls
echo.
echo.
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host '%1' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
      [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set %2=%%p
Goto :eof
::***********************************        
:Good
Color 0B                  
Cls
echo.
echo                     Good password
::TimeOut /T 2 /NoBreak>nul
echo Your password stored as : "!Pass2!" without quotes
pause>nul
Goto :Eof
::***********************************
:Bad
Color 0C
Cls
echo.
echo             Wrong password try again
::TimeOut /T 2 /NoBreak>nul
echo  Press any key to retry again
pause>nul
Goto :CreatePassword
::***********************************
```